# How to extract only cells with the values <0?

Tags: r

How to just extract the cells where the values are lower than 0 including NAs ?

I would like to have a vector as an output.

Comment: And we would like you to: A: provide a reproducible example. B: Use Google before posting basic R questions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Tried google but didn't know what's the proper question... Thx for your help. Just think about creating a thread about "reproducible answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the way to subset items from a vector using `?'['`

```
> set.seed(0)
> x <- c(rnorm(10),NA)
> x
 [1]  1.262954285 -0.326233361  1.329799263  1.272429321  0.414641434
 [6] -1.539950042 -0.928567035 -0.294720447 -0.005767173  2.404653389
[11]           NA
> x[x<0 |is.na(x)]
[1] -0.326233361 -1.539950042 -0.928567035 -0.294720447 -0.005767173
[6]           NA
```